# How to make Android UI that looks exactly the same in every screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm currently working on an Android Application development. I have written a UI Code that looks perfect in Android Simulator But when the same App is run on my Android Smartphone, the UI gets distorted.

I have tried my layouts including LinearLayout, Relative Layout & Constraint Layout but the results are not very much different.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:text="PHYSICS"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="460sp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mechanics" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Oscillations and Waves" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Thermodynamics" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Solid States" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What do I need to make a UI that looks the same on every Android screen when the screen size is 4 inches or 5.

**Original UI on Emulator**
[image: Original UI on Emulator]

**This is what it appears on my Smartphone**
[image: This is what it appears on my Smartphone]

Comment: _I need to make a UI that looks the same on every Android screen_. That is very, **very** ambitious ...

Comment: You wont be able to make a UI that looks identical on every Android screen, because Android screens comes in all shapes and sizes. It's impossible. You need to design your layouts in such a way that they are positioned relative to each other, so they can adapt to the device they're on. Make use of weights and relative positioning more, and avoid setting absolute values (like you have with your linear layout, set to 460sp)

Comment: Post pictures of what it actually looks like and what you want it to look like.  We can't give you one answer to your big question, but we can help on issues in this code-  if we know what the problem is

Comment: @GabeSechan Added the pics, I hope now you understand my problem.

Comment: Fixing your dp and sp use will fix the spacing differences.  You have them reversed.  As for the not fitting vertically issue-  different physical sizes will always cause that problem.  Put it in a ScrollView so it scrolls to see all of them

Answer (score 1):

In your layout you have used **sp** for padding and height and **dp** for textSize. You should use **dp** for padding and height (view dimension) and **sp** for textSize.

Comment: I have changed according to what you said. But still, half of the UI is shown in my smartphone whose screen size is 4 inches.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DP instead of SP. SP is influenced by the Android user's font preferences, which can make it look different.

Comment: SP should be used for text sizes, because otherwise people with vision sizes won't get the text magnification they need.  It should almost never be used for anything else though